# post on multiple friends facebook wall

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios4

I make application with only one facebook wall post. It works good for me using FBConnect. but now i want wall post to multiple friends at a time on one button click. Is it possible for post on multiple friends wall? If it is possible then suggest me.

My Code :

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrData objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"]], @"to",
                                   @"post on facebook", @"name",
                                   @"facebook wall post", @"description",
                                   @"http://m.facebook.com/apps/myapp", @"link",
                                   nil];

    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [[delegate facebook] dialog:@"feed"
                      andParams:params
                    andDelegate:self];
```

Please reply me.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Yeah, please add the code you are currently using to post on a friend's wall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the feed dialog then you have no choice but to open a dialog per friend.

What you can do though is request the `publish_stream` parameter which lets you publish as the logged in user on his or his friends walls.
After you get that permission you simply send a request to fb and it gets published, without the use of a dialog, which let's you send as many requests as you like.

On the ios sdk it's done with [Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/request/).

Comment: i use this code but it dont post.    [delegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"123456789/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work"? You get an error or what? Also, are you sure you have the `publish_stream` permission?

Comment: Thanks a lot....It works for me. I made some mistake in my code regarding permission.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know how to post users wall then you can do this task using following approach, Or see [this](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) link for help

1. Get Face book fiends id for all your friends.
2. Save in array.
3. Iterate loop array's length and post one by one on friends wall.

Comment: I got facebook id in array. but when iterating with my code then open many pop up window with wall post. but i need only one pop up window with many wall post.