# Facebook api Javascript post to friends wall

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So i got this js code:

```
FB.ui({ 
    method:'feed',
    from: $('.j-login-user').data('id'),
    to: userId,
}, function(response) {
```

My question is, can i post to multiple friends at the same time?

If so, how? So far i try:

```
FB.ui({ 
    method:'feed',
    from: $('.j-login-user').data('id'),
    to: 1234, 12334,
}, function(response) {
```

And

```
FB.ui({ 
    method:'feed',
    from: $('.j-login-user').data('id'),
    to: [1234, 12334],
}, function(response) {
```

But they both return this FB msg:

```
API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: 4302516,842604 does not resolve to a valid user ID
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to share multiple post on friend's wall in objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834007/how-to-share-multiple-post-on-friends-wall-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think you can do more than one

the documentation refers to 'username or id' in singular
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/