# Facebook : Post same message on multiple friend's wall

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

To post on Facebook friend's wall below code can be used.

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"100785345503503", @"to",
                                   @"Caption value", @"caption",
                                   @"Message to post on wall", @"description",
                                   @"http://www.website.com", @"link",
                                   @"http://www.website.com/img/logo.png", @"picture",
                                   nil];
[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                           parameters:params
                                              handler:
    ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error)

    {

    }];
```

I know that we can execute above code multiple times to post on multiple friends' wall but issue is that if there are 10 friends I want to post message on the wall of, then user will have see dialog 10 times which is not user friendly.

So is there a way to display only one dialog but post message on multiple friend's wall?

Comment: Similar :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834007/how-to-share-multiple-post-on-friends-wall-in-objective-c?rq=1

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is spam